# Starting with Polly basics

Tags: c#, polly, retry-logic, resiliency

I'm pretty new with Polly and I'm trying to understand how works, starting from the very basics.

To test the retries I tried to create a code (Print) that has 33% to generate a `DivideByZeroException`. When the error is generated it raise up to `policy.Execute` seems don't managed by Polly.

Someone can help me to adjust this code? I'm using .Net Framework 4.7.2.

```
using System;
using Polly;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var policy = Policy
                        .Handle<DivideByZeroException>()
                        .Retry();

        policy.Execute(() => Print());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Print()
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        int a = rand.Next(1000, 2000);
        int b = rand.Next(0, 2);
        Console.WriteLine("a = {0} - b {1}", a, b);
        int c = a / b;
        Console.WriteLine("c = {0}", c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of what you’re seeing versus what you expect to see? Note that because you’re using `Random`, the exception might not actually occur.

Comment: Try creating the `Random` once as a single static variable, instead of creating a new `Random` each time the `Print` runs.

Answer (score 2):

If you set `b` = `0`, instead of using `Random`, you'll see it is handling the exception, but it's not retrying forever - you'll see it print output twice before failing. So it means, in the case of using `Random`, it's *sometimes* setting `b` to `0` multiple times in a row, in which case the policy exhausts its retries, and so it throws.

You can configure the policy to increase the number of retries using `Retry(n)`. Alternatively, you can use `RetryForever()`.

If you don't want your calling code to throw when the retries are exhausted, you can use capture the result instead:

```
var result = policy.ExecuteAndCapture(() => Print());
if (result.Outcome == OutcomeType.Failure)
{
    // result.FinalException contains the exception
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply...with .Retry(1) seems working...I imagined that .Retry() was like Retry(1) but seems that I was wrong.

Comment: @user1812102 `Retry()` is the same as `Retry(1)`. Have you set `b = 0`? If not, you're just rolling the dice with `Random` as to whether it works or not.

Comment: Maybe I made confusion looking at the output aftert the error, anyway now seems clear...